# ASP.NET application calling TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.2 web services

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ssl, tls1.2

My ASP.NET application calls multiple vendors' web services that have been recently reconfigured to enforce TLS 1.2. One of the providers, however, fell behind and continues to use TLS 1.0. As a result, the application is failing with

> Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

The project was targeting .NET 4.5 runtime, which I have changed to 4.7.1 to use TLS 1.2 as default in attempt to avoid code changes (4.6 would suffice). That, of course, broke the part of the application that used TLS 1.0 configured web service.

Specifying security protocols as shown below had no effect.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I realized that at some point I've disabled TLS 1.0 in the Windows registry. To fix the problem, navigate to:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client

and make sure the protocol is enabled. In my case, I added "Enabled" REG_DWORD with the value of "1". You may want to change "DisabledByDefault" but I opted for a manual override. Reboot is required for changes to take affect.